# How Can I Display Random Activity On Button Click In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display a random activity after the ad loads, but it doesn't display random activities on the button click it just goes on to the next level with the ad reloading. I would like to be able to click the button, have the ad display, then have the random activity show instead of these level pages showing. How would I be able to do that?

```
package com.ddt.ddts;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
// Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "testing";

private static final int START_LEVEL = 1;
private int mLevel;
private Button mNextLevelButton;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private TextView mLevelTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    // Create the next level button, which tries to show an interstitial when clicked.
    mNextLevelButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.next_level_button));
    mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
    mNextLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });


    // Create the text view to show the level number.
    mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_level_button);
    mLevel = START_LEVEL;

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in values/strings.xml).
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-123456789/12356");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Proceed to the next level.
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    });
    loadInterstitial();

    }

public void button(View v){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x=rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch(x){
        case 1:
            intent.setClass(this,t1.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent.setClass(this,t2.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent.setClass(this,t3.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        goToNextLevel();
    }
}

private void loadInterstitial() {
    // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
    mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void goToNextLevel() {
    // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
    mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
    loadInterstitial();
}


}
```

Comment: If you directly call ads on button google catch you and block your admob account.

Comment: if you have like 5 activities, store their names in an array and create a random integer between 0 - 5 (exclusive) and based on that get the name from the array and start the activity.

Comment: @MaherNabeel hey thanks for the reply.  i tried doing this
    public void button(View v){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x=rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        switch(x){
            case 1:
                intent.setClass(this,tip1.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                intent.setClass(this,tip2.class);
                break;
            case 3:
                intent.setClass(this,tip3.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: @MaherNabeel 
But it keeps going to 'level' classes it never displays the random activities. I know i have a bunch of code in there that I can take out or modify but I am not sure where..

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can show interstitial and rewarded videos randomly:

```
private void showAd(Intent intent) {
    // every 30 clicks:
    // 5 interstitial ads
    // 1 rewarded videos

    int max_displays = 30;
    int num_interstitial_ads = 5;
    int num_rewarded_videos = 1;

    Random r = new Random();
    int intRandom = r.nextInt(max_displays);
    if ((intRandom >= 0) && (intRandom < num_interstitial_ads)) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        if (intRandom <= num_interstitial_ads + num_rewarded_videos) {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                nextIntent = intent;
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            } else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        if (AppSettings.DEBUG_MODE)
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AppSettings.REWARDED_VIDEO_AD_ID_TEST,
                    new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        else
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AppSettings.REWARDED_VIDEO_AD_ID,
                    new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```